# Identifying the minimal set of columns that can be used to define a unique instance in a database table

Tags: sql, artificial-intelligence

Some context here:

I am developing a comparison tool that coalesces, formats and concatenates all column values for the individual rows in a table. This single string is further reduced in size by converting it into an md5 hash.

In addition to reducing the entire row's contents to an md5 hash, I will do the same with the columns that constitute the row's primary key.

The problem I have is the lack of Primary Key for some tables so I need some programmatic way of discovering the optimal (minimal) set of columns that constitute the unique instance for a row.

I know how to do this through manual data profiling of course but this is not an exact science and no two tables share the same formula.

I was thinking maybe AI is a good choice to use to derive the unique key of a table based on its data, but I am not well versed in AI.

Any suggestions or thoughts on where to go from here?

Comment: How _exactly_ are you defining "optimal"? In terms of bytes, in terms of number of columns, or something else, and how close to do you need to be to "optimal" - if you have something which is 0.1% away from optimal, is that good enough?

Comment: performance wise...the goal is to compare as many rows as possible as quickly as possible...since we are reducing the footprint of the rows as well as the primary key...we want to arrive at the se two md5 hashes in the most optimal manner (i.e fast)..Also, the fewer the number of columns the better

Comment: Prefer SHA3 over MD5. And rather than defaulting to "we'll just take a 160-bit prefix", give a moment's thought to how many rows you may have and how much collision resistance you [actually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) need.

Comment: md5 is chosen due to its small footprint. For my purposes, I accept the tiny risk of collision in exchange for the gains in performance of comparing smaller hex strings

Comment: Can you explain why you are taking a hash of the primary key? Just trying to understand how it is going to be used.

Comment: i am comparing row data across two different databases, reducing the data to a single hash ... the primary key permits me to associate the hash to the original row

Answer (score 4):

Avoid over-engineering your application with the intent of generating primary keys for row-by-row table comparison. Here's why:

Immutability Verification: Confirming the immutability of columns is feasible only if the table has been explicitly designed to support this. Without such provisions, there's no reliable method to ensure column values remain unchanged over time.

Business Context for Primary Keys: Primary keys necessitate a deep understanding of the business context, and attempting to infer this automatically could lead to suboptimal selection of columns.

Customer-Driven Key Selection: The most suitable keys are determined through manual data profiling conducted by the customer, not automatically by the application.

The optimal approach is to develop a user-friendly tool that aids users in identifying potential candidate keys. However, the responsibility of selecting these keys should ultimately rest with the user.

While there might be a temptation to automate every aspect of your application, it's important to recognize that doing so could inadvertently lead to user frustration rather than providing a helpful solution.

Comment: I don't agree this is over-engineering the solution -- it is simply a convenience for unsophisticated users to generate good keys for the purpose of comparing data. I prefer to implement a solution that takes a "hands off" approach as much as possible. The less work the user does, the better.

Comment: If the application does a poor job at generating your keys, those "unsophisticated users" won't be able to tell the difference either. If you prefer a "hands-off" approach, it's best to only accept tables that already have primary or unique keys defined.

Answer (score 2):

Forget AI for the moment. It's not going to help you.

If your data is static, you can check whether any column (or any plausible combination of columns) constitutes a possible primary key by comparing `select count(*) from table` with `select count(distinct column_1) from table`. If those are equal, you have a primary key.

If this does not get you a result (and it most likely won't) there are at least two options, one complicated and one very simple at the expense of some space:

- Complicated: Combine almost-unique columns to check whether they would together constitute a composite primary key. This will take some experimentation as the number of candidates grows with each additional column that you consider.
- Simple: Just add an artificial primary key column to your table and fill it with values from a sequence or UUIDs. Voila, a primary key. You don't even need to hash it as the hash would not convey any meaning, so a meaningless primary key is just as good.

  - Database-specific zero-overhead variant of the simple approach: Some databases provide row ids, for example ORACLE's `ROWID` or PostgreSQL's `CTID`. These can change when rows are inserted or deleted so are not usable as a primary key replacement in a live database, but would be usable as long as you don't modify the data.

Comment: I know how to profile the data -- the problem is how to arrive at at a programmatic approach to profile and arrive at the list of columns... I am building this compare tool for clients so I cannot tell the customer to add a key... The idea I had was to prioritize mandatory columns that had the most variation in values (from most varied to least) and run GROUP BY HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 using one column, and then two and so on until i got no rows returned...

Comment: I have no issue programmatically generating the queries, the problem i have is the choice of heuristic algorithm that lets me target column combinations that are fruitful rather than wasteful ... For example, if I choose all mandatory columns, ok, that might be unique but not a terribly meaningful key... Also, the problem of those columns might be subject to updates which would make a terrible PK. I am thinking this problem is unsolvable because it requires some intuition and thats why i considered ai as a possible solution